# How to I code for placeholders in email messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, design-patterns

The requirement is that within the application I am working in that I make all the emails available to be edited.

The obvious solution is to store all the messages in a database and to use a text editor for the user to edit the messages.

However I am wondering how to design this when it comes to placeholders within the email message.

The placeholders for a message will have to also be stored in the database. A message can have many placeholders. A placeholder can be in many messages.

I could allow the user to select a placeholder from a list of placeholders when they insert one.

The email message will need to include placeholder markers, typically {0}, {1} etc, but for display purposes this will need to be more user friendly, such as $WebsiteLink$ for example.
Some placeholders are straight forward, such as a link to the website which only changes depending on the deployment, or the name of the logged in user.

Other placeholders are more complicated. They depend on getting the information from the database at that particular time, for example a selected team member name.
So for this placeholder instead of holding some static text, I need to maybe invoke a method or event to get that information.

I am not clear how to do this. Can you help?

I hope the spec is clear, let me know if not?

Comment: Do you need some kind of pattern for email body?

Comment: I need to think how the user can insert placeholders in the email body. Maybe from a list of placeholders, select and drag and drop, but I suspect that is hard for a web app.

Comment: Imho, best solution is to use some special tags for users.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple `String.Format` replacement check out [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx) (and the followups) by Phil Haack.

The solutions there mean that you can use named placeholders like `{name}` or `{date}` instead of `{0}`.

This doesn't solve the whole UI problem but at least the placeholders are clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can do it as goths suggested (or even take a look at [this](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/), I haven't used it but it looks sweet), or there's the other way:

1.You build a HTML template, let's call it `mailTemplate.html`:

(Beware, tables...)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <%MY_PLACEHOLDER%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

2.Then you can simply use this in a method, assuming that `templatePath` is the physical path to your template file:

```
var mailDefinition = new MailDefinition
                         {
                              BodyFileName = templatePath,
                              IsBodyHtml = true,
                              From = ... // you'll have to fill that
                         };
string replacementForPlaceholder = "Look at me!";
var replacements = new ListDictionary { { "<%MY_PLACEHOLDER%>", replacementForPlaceholder }};

string recipients = ... // well, specify recipients
var message = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(recipients, replacements, new LiteralControl());
```

And your message is ready to be sent. If you don't go too crazy with the HTML tables and whatnot, the mail gracefully degrades to text if the recipient has disabled HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Last month I implemented the below Template based EmailModule that uses Razor syntax. It should work well in your case. It is easy to implement.

http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc

Thanks to Kazi Manzur Rashid.

Comment: Good link but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

C# now supports interpolation. For anyone still worrying about this, take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).